# Primes in the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: number-theory

Are there infinitely many prime numbers that are Fibonacci numbers as well? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Fibonacci Primes wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_prime)

Comment: In which context does this question arise?

Comment: There are sequences known with $\gcd(a_0,a_1)=1$, $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$ for all $n\ge1$, and all $a_i$ composite.